# How to abort browser reload/refresh in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am not sure how you can abort a browser reload using ember's route events. The `willTransition` event only gets triggered when you click the back button or just change the route. I have not been able to find how I can stop page reload for example while an upload is still in progress.

Comment: There are some things that should always be in control of the user and reloading a page is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `beforeunload` on the `window` element. This at least allows to present a "Do you really want to leave" like popup by the browser. See [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload). Some browsers even allow to show a custom message.

There also is an ember addon for this: [ember-onbeforeunload](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-onbeforeunload).
See the addons [route mixin](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-onbeforeunload/blob/master/addon/mixins/confirmation.js) for how this works.